# A tag with inner span can't catch click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The click event is not fired when clicked on the red area.
The span padding changes on `a:active` state.

How to target that 'moved area' without targeting the span itself?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KC2ct/

Markup:

```
<a href="#"> <span>TEXTO</span> </a>
<p>debug</p>
```

CSS:

```
a{background-color: red}
span{color: white; background-color: blue}
a{display: block; width: 64px; height: 22px}
span{padding:5px}
a:active span{padding: 6px}
p.click{color: green}
```

JS:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('p').toggleClass('click');
});
```

How it looks like normal state (note the red right area):

[image: a busy cat]

How it looks like when pressed (:active):

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: I can click on the red area just fine.

Comment: What browser(s) and version(s) is this happening in?

Comment: Are you developing for IE6 on a winXP machine? It works fine in all my browsers

Comment: Moderators can't transfer ownership of questions. The easiest way to fix this is to ask your coworker to post this question using their account and flagging this for a merge. Or you can contact the team at `team@stackoverflow.com` and ask them to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated your CSS take a look at your updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/KC2ct/5/

Comment: I still get the problem in firefox if I have my cursor on the pixel adjacent to the span to the right.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly,  you might want to use onmousedown instead of click...

Answer (score 0):

Add display:block to your span and hide the red area:

span{padding:5px;display:block;}